# Spring Java - Running process performs tasks once a day

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, scheduled-tasks

I have a little problem (I am using spring version 3.1.1). I want to start a process or thread that performs a task in one day.

So for example:
I have a list of users and every user has a total count of days as field.

class User{
String ...
String ...
DateTime countDays = ...12-12-12...
}

So what I want to do is, when i start my application (running), I want to perform a task everyday:
Loop through the list of users
Check the countDays
If countDays is greater then 14 for example
Send something to the user....

I do know how to loop through and send something. I dont know how I can start an object en let it perform one task in a day. Create a bean, construct it and use sleep function????

Hope somebody can help me out, I thank you! :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also use the @Scheduled Annotation akin to:

```
@Scheduled(cron="0 0 * * *")
public void doStuff() {
   ..
}
```

Check the decumentation here: [there are a lot of different methods to do it](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html).

Answer (score 4):

Spring supports the Quartz scheduler very well...

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html

You could set a task to run once a day (at midnight, for example) with a CRON trigger bean

```
<bean id="cronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="usersJob" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 * * *" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Wow... That was fast. I think I found what I was looking for: TimerTask. Man.. I thank you!!

Comment: Spring also has native support for cron triggers, so you don't need Quartz if you don't want it.  The link provided by Zutty has all the details.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of Spring's [TaskScheduler](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/TaskExecutor.html) and [Trigger](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/Trigger.html) interfaces.  A TaskScheduler is responsible for scheduling tasks (a Runnable object) for execution and a Trigger is responsible for determining execution times.

For your case, the [ThreadPoolTaskScheduler](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.html) implementation of TaskScheduler should be more than sufficient.  It adapts a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor as a TaskScheduler.

For the trigger implementation, the [CronTrigger](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronTrigger.html) is perfect for your needs.  It can be used to create an trigger strategy so that the task is executed every day at the same time.

Example Java code:

```
Runnable task = /* your task */
TaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
scheduler.schedule(task, new CronTrigger("0 0 * * *"));
```